# Generating Combinations NOT Permutations. How?

Tags: python-3.x, combinatorics

After some online research, It seems a lot of people tend to confuse Combinations with Permutations.

Example:

The powerball lotery has 5 numbers 1 - 59 and a last powerball number 1 - 35.

Question:

Similar to the Excel function COMBIN() how does one go about generating all combinations of a set or subset of items regardless of internal order?

Combinations are distinct from Permutaions, for which the internal order is significant.

First 5:
59 x 58 x 57 x 56 x 55 = 5, 006, 386

Powerball:
5,006,386 X 35 = 175, 223, 510

I'd like you to help me generate the first 5 combinations and then a separate one with First 5 + Powerball.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for an algorithm or a library? If the latter, take a look at `itertools`.

Comment: I'm on a blackberry right now... I figured it'd be itertools. Just hoping for a sample.

Comment: For example `itertools.combinations(range(1, 59+1), 5)`. Not sure, however, what you mean by "first five". You could call `next` on that generator five times, if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: First 5 Picks???? If the number 59 is picked then there are now only 58 numbers to to choose from and so on. I just want a list of all Combinations NOT permutations of possible results.

Comment: I meant your statement "I'd like you to help me generate the first 5 combinations". What exactly did you mean by that? If you want all the combinations, do `list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 59+1), 5))`, but better make sure you have enough RAM...

Comment: @tobias_k, The term "First 5" is a marketing term for the lottery.  Vini does not want the first five combinations, he wants all the combinations (or maybe he wants to compute how many there are) for the "First 5" and "Powerball" games.

Comment: Still not entirely clear what you *need* that list for. Maybe there's an easier way than generating the entire list for what you really want to do?

Comment: I think he wants to generate a different type of list based on the same principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer as well as in the comments, to generate all the combinations for the "First 5" you can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
first5 = itertools.combinations(range(1, 59+1), 5)
```

and for the product of those and the "Powerball" number, use `itertools.product`:

```
first5andPowerball = itertools.product(first5, range(1, 35+1))
```

Both of those are *generator* objects. To turn them into actual lists, just use the `list` function, e.g., `list(first5)`, but those lists will be *huge* and I do not know what use you could have for them.

If you want to get just *one* random combination (like in a lottery drawing), it is much easier not to use `combinations`, but to `shuffle` the numbers and pick the first five, like  shuffling a deck of cards and picking the first five off the top:

```
numbers = range(1, 59+1)
random.shuffle(numbers)
first5 = numbers[:5]
bonus = random.randint(1, 35)
print first5, bonus
```

Or even simpler, using `sample` (thanks to @dansalmo for this hint)

```
first5 = random.sample(range(1, 59+1), 5)
```

Comment: `random.sample(range(1, 59+1), 5), random.randint(1, 35)`

Comment: Ok. So is it possible to run a list of winning lotery picks of 5 against all possible picks within that range and find out it's index?

Comment: @Vini You mean, you have a list of all the numbers, generated in order (starting with (1,2,3,4,5,1) and so on), and you want to determine the position of, e.g., (34,58,1,14,7,4) in this list?

Comment: Yes! Just another way to analyze winning numbers by index.

Comment: Or! If I can insert each combination into a MySQL database that the primary keys would serve as indexes.

Comment: @Vini I guess you could use `enumerate` to create a (massively huge) dictionary mapping winning numbers to their positions in the generator sequence, i.e., `{(1,2,3,4,5,1): 1, (1,2,3,4,5,2): 2, ...}`, and then use this dict to quickly get the position, but as I said, this dictionary would be gigantic. As for a formula: No idea, but I'll think about it (sounds interesting). But again: Could you explain what you are trying to do? Maybe there's another way...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an illustrative example showing how to list the combinations for a game that chooses only 6 numbers:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(range(1, 6+1), 5))
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5, 6),
(1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

Here is an example for the number of combinations for "First 5":

```
>>> len(list(combinations(range(1, 59+1), 5)))
5006386
```

If you wanted the entire list, just remove the `len()` function.

To get all combinations for Pick 2 of 4 with Powerball of 5 requires taking the Cartiesian product of the two combinations:

```
>>> list((x,y) for x in combinations(range(1,4+1),2) for y in range(1,5+1))
[((1, 2), 1), ((1, 2), 2), ((1, 2), 3), ((1, 2), 4), ((1, 2), 5), ((1, 3), 1), ((1, 3), 2), ((1, 3), 3), ((1, 3), 4), ((1, 3), 5), ((1, 4), 1), ((1, 4), 2), ((1, 4), 3), ((1, 4), 4), ((1, 4), 5), ((2, 3), 1), ((2, 3), 2), ((2, 3), 3), ((2, 3), 4), ((2, 3), 5), ((2, 4), 1), ((2, 4), 2), ((2, 4), 3), ((2, 4), 4), ((2, 4), 5), ((3, 4), 1), ((3, 4), 2), ((3, 4), 3), ((3, 4), 4), ((3, 4), 5)]
```

You can see how fast the combinations grow even with small numbers!

To get all of the Powerball combinations would be:

```
>>> list((x,y) for x in combinations(range(1,59+1),2) for y in range(1,35+1))
```

But it is too large for my system.

Adding DSM's comment:

Create a generator using product:

```
from itertools import combinations, product
cgen = product(combinations(range(1,59+1),5), range(1,35+1))
for c in cgen:
    #write c to file
```

or you can gather some number of c's together before writing to a file.

Each combination will be a tuple of the form: `((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)`

Comment: I think it'd be cleaner to use `product` for the "First 5" + "Powerball" case, e.g. `product(combinations(range(1,59+1),5), range(1,35+1))`.  Then you could do `sum(1 for p in prod..)` and count them without materializing the list.

Comment: Right on. Here's a word list generator I've created that writes to file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845330/wordlist-generator-split-file-size-how Because of the RAM issues you've pointed out, how can I add your code to my existing code?

Answer (score 1):

Per the question "is it possible to run a list of winning lotery picks of 5 against all possible picks within that range and find out it's index?" in the comments of @tobias_k's answer:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> all = list(combinations(range(1, 59+1), 5))
>>> all.index((1, 2, 3, 4, 59))
54
>>> all.index((32, 42, 43, 54, 59))
4922705
```

The above is workable, but the index lookup time gets longer (< 1 sec) towards the end of the list.  Trying to create a dict causes a memory error for me.

It should certainly be possible to create a formula to derive the index without creating the list.  You should post it as another question.